# Reflection in Rebol: Is it possible to know the script/object/function that is executing?

Tags: rebol

If not will this be possible in R3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and No.

Technically, no.....Functions do not have names, they are anonymous. The same function may be assigned to more than one word, so the actual name is problematic.

```
do func [][print "hi world"]    ;; this function explicitly has no name at all

f1: func [] [print "yo world"]  ;; here's a single function with three names
f2: :f1
f3: :f2
```

In practice in some cases, Yes....You can grab the current name (if there is one) with a trick: capture an error, and the error object contains the name on the stack:

```
 f3: func [/local eo] [eo: disarm try [0 / 0 ] print ["name is " eo/where]]
 f4: :f3
```

Try it:

```
 >> f3
 name is  f3
 >> f4
 name is  f4
```

There is an exhaustive discussion here:
http://www.rebol.org/ml-display-thread.r?m=rmlGLPJ

Comment: Hi Sunanda thanks, but then there should still be possible to reference it generically with something like self or this ?

Comment: Or there should be a system variable which should store this contextual info like system/options/script does.

Comment: Sadly, 'self means the thing itself, not the name of any word it is assigned to. This "trick" does not work with objects/contexts: probe o1: context [o1-name: get in disarm try [ 0 / 0] 'where o1-self: self]

Comment: Hasn't anyone suggest this to Carl even if it is in Rebol 4 I really want it :)